# disable all the links in my slider panes using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How do i disable all the links in my slider panes using jquery?

Basically every single `<a href...` within my parent div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider").on('click', 'a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('no navigation');
    });
});​
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ha4pR/)

More info about jQuery PreventDefault [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.classname-of-parent-div').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//You could alse use $('a') if you want to disable ALL links
$('.sliding-pane a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```